# ZeroBrain Studio cant open utf-16 le codind ini file

Tags: zerobrane

Im tryin to open uft 16 le code ini file in Zerobarane Studio and get error: Binary file is shown as read-only as it is only partially loaded.
However it opens fine in win 10 notepad.

Answer (score 0):

You can use version 1.90 of ZeroBrane Studio, as it has better handling of binary files, but it will not decode UTF-16 files for you, as it expects UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Yes, i installed new version and now i can open this file without errors, but unreadable anyway. And another little question: dark mode is the same as dark theme? Becourse i get this new version 1.9 and i have not any dark colors (my system is in dark mode however).

Comment: If you don't set the color scheme in the IDE explicitly, then it should switch to the dark color mode based on the OS setting. If you do set the color scheme explicitly (for example, to Monokai), then it will keep the same scheme. What OS are you on?